# Is there any way to solve the problem of string APP running error in cytoscape?

Tags: string, cytoscape

I am working on [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/) 3.10.1 and have [stringApp](https://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/stringapp) 2.0.2 installed in my system. Today, I tried importing 2500+ genes to stringApp.
Cytoscape opens fine and I installed the stringApp. When I try to search using the `STRING: protein query` two dialog boxes opens with the following information:

```
Getting annotations 
Query returned no terms
your query returned no results
```

I've tried downloading older versions of Cytoscape and stringApp, and changing the network environment, but failed. I use the same operation with someone else's software and it works. I don't know where my setup went wrong. I hope the program works properly.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say which species for your proteins, but you need to make sure the Species matches the species for your proteins.  The species is set in the settings menu (three horizontal lines) to the right of the input panel.  Also, how are your protein names separated?  Ideally, they are one protein per line.

Comment: Hi Scooter. Please refrain from signing your posts. The profile card is regarded as a signature on Stack Overflow.